# how to initialize server context using gsoap to enable simple authentication (server only authentication)

Tags: c++, authentication, ssl, gsoap

I have server.pem and a server.jks for a back-end which is my client (soapui). I initialize ssl server context in order to enable simple authentication for my web service as follow:

```
int ssl_connection_flag = SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT; // Simple authentication

int soap_result = soap_ssl_server_context(soap_object,
                                                ssl_connection_flag,//SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION,//m_ssl_connection_flag,
                                                m_key_file.c_str(),//Settings::instance()->get_cert_mngr_tls_certificate_path().c_str(),//"D:\\ICA\\Release\\currentStore\\TLSCertificate.pem",//m_ssl_private_key_file_path.c_str(),/* keyfile: required when server must authenticate to clients (see SSL docs on how to obtain this file) */
                                                l_recover.c_str(),//"changeit",//PWDHelper::instance()->retrieve_pwd("k-tls-key").c_str(),//"changeit",//"12345678",//"server_key_password",/* password to read the key file (not used with GNUTLS) */
                                                m_ca_certs_file.c_str(),//Settings::instance()->get_cert_mngr_ca_path().c_str(),//"D:\\ICA\\Release\\currentStore\\CA.pem",//"D:\\CertificatBrahim\\CAs.pem",//m_ssl_ca_file_path.c_str(), /* optional cacert file to store trusted certificates */                                                 
                                                NULL, /* optional capath to directory with trusted certificates */
                                                NULL,/* DH file name or DH key len bits (minimum is 512, e.g. "512") to generate DH param, if NULL use RSA */
                                                NULL,
                                                NULL);
```

The trouble is, when I look for in wireshark after sending my request from SoapUI to a remote PC where is located my server. The decoding looks like there is a mutual authentication going on.

But when I change

> SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT

with

> SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION

, and sent the same request, in wireshark it looks like there is a simple (only server authentication) going on.

But that confuses me, because if I follow gSoap documentation, the TLS/SSL option SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION, disable both client and server authentication.

Then my question is what am I doing wrong?

thanks in advance for your responses.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The `SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION` flag on the server side does not prevent the client from requesting the server to authenticate. This flag disables the requirement for a peer to authenticate to the requesting side. In your case the client is the requesting side and the flag is set at the server side.

Comment: Thx for your reply